# Bind to the success event of an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

On a website I'm working on there is an AJAX request defined like this:

```
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                jQuery('.sib_loader').hide();
            // some more actions take place here...
```

That JS is in a file I can't edit because it may be overwritten at anytime...

Can I somehow "hook" or bind my own code to that AJAX success event and and a couple of additional actions that I need to happen?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: You could also use websockets(eg SignalR) and change the back end to send an event to your front-end when your ajax request completes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it`s too complicatedm, but I would do

```
    // Custom trigger using passed data
    jQuery( document.body ).on( 'your_ajax_done', afterYourAjaxDone );
    function afterYourAjaxDone(data){
        console.log(data);
    }


    function doYourAjax(){
        yourAjaxPromise(postData).then(function(data){
            // You can do stuff right here or have hook for custom trigger passing data
            jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'your_ajax_done', data);
        });
    }

    // Ajax as Promise
    function yourAjaxPromise(postData) {
        return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    resolve(data)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    reject(error)
                },
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Note OP cannot edit the javascript he posted